# How to create vertical ruler in CSS/html?

Tags: html, css

i want to create a vertical ruler in css and html. maybe this picture display my purpose.how create this vertical ruler?

my code is :

```
<div>
 <li class='ruler'>0</li>
 <li class='ruler'>5</li>
 <li class='ruler'>10</li>
 <li class='ruler'>15</li>
 <li class='ruler'>20</li>
 </div>

.ruler {
 background: #ffffff;
 box-shadow: 0 -1px 1em hsl(60, 60%, 84%) inset;
 border-radius: 2px;
 border-left: 6px solid #000;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
 color: #000000;
 margin: 0;
 height: 80px;
 list-style: none;
 text-align: right;
 width: 60px;
 }
```

[image]

Comment: We will not write code for you. Show us what you have tried and then we can help you from there. You should show some effort into creating this so it doesn't just turn in to us writing code for you.

Comment: What are the units of measurement? Is that penultimate line *meant* to be skewed for some reason?

Comment: Have you tried <ul class="ruler-wrap"> .ruler-wrap {border-left: 6px solid black}  Then set the li to have no margin or padding left. And remove the left border from your li

Comment: @David Thomas units of measurement can be cm or inch or other. like this http://jsfiddle.net/thirdender/kwcug/ but vertical and similar picture.

Comment: Just rotate the scale by 90deg

Comment: Someone does not like my answer. Sorry guys. I deleted it

Comment: @Lafontein i thank you very very much. your answer is very attractive because similar picture exactly. again i thank you.

Comment: @user1327621 Thank you. I hope you can use my method

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is how I'd (probably) try to implement this idea:

```css
ol,
li {
  /* removing the default list counters/markers: */
  list-style-type: none;
}
ol {
  /* resetting the counter so every <ol>
     has an independent count: */
  counter-reset: marker;
}
li {
  /* 'real world' measurements are perhaps not
     entirely faithful on screen: */
  height: 1cm;
  border-top: 1px solid #000;
  /* including the border in the height of the element: */
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 2.5em;
  /* incrementing the counter: */
  counter-increment: marker;
  /* to position the counter relative
     to the <li>: */
  position: relative;
  border-left: 2px solid #000;
}
li:first-child,
li:nth-child(5n) {
  /* longer mark for the first and
     every fifth marker: */
  width: 5em;
}
/* preventing a 'tail' on the <ol> from the
   height of the last <li> (the counter is
   displayed at the top, not the bottom): */
li:last-child {
  height: 0;
}
li:first-child::after,
li:nth-child(5n)::after {
  /* positioning the pseudo-element that
     contains the counter: */
  position: absolute;
  /* vertically-centering it alongside the
     top border: */
  top: -0.5em;
  /* moving it the full width of the element,
     outside of the right side of the element: */
  left: 100%;
  height: 1em;
  line-height: 1em;
  width: 2em;
  text-align: center;
  /* specifying the counter to use: */
  content: counter(marker);
}
```

```html
<ol id="rule">
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ol>
```

References:

- [`box-sizing`](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-ui-3/#box-sizing).
- [CSS Generated Content, automatic numbering and lists](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/generate.html)

Comment: Nice answer and use of counter and content!

Comment: @ThePragmatick: thank you very much, and, to user1327621, you're very welcome indeed, I'm glad to have been of help! :)

Comment: Hey just one thing. Don't scales start from 0? I think one extra marker would be added to top. Then marker styles can be removed from first-child. Anyways its nice!

Comment: You can also use li:nth-child(5n-4) and initialize at -1 to get it to start at 0.

Answer (score 2):

```css
#number1 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 70px;
  top: 15px;
}
#number2 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50px;
  top: 65px;
}
#number3 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 70px;
  top: 123px;
}
#number4 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50px;
  top: 179px;
}
```

```html
<div id="ruller">
  <table cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 height=609 width=86 style="font-size:0px;height:609;width:86">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <table cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 height=609 width=50 style="font-size:0px;height:609px;width:50px">
          <tr height=0>
            <td width=1 />
            <td width=1 />
            <td width=1 />
            <td width=1 />
            <td width=1 />
            <td width=1 />
            <td width=1 />
            <td width=1 />
            <td width=1 />
            <td width=1 />
            <td width=1 />
            <td width=1 />
            <td width=1 />
            <td width=1 />
            <td width=1 />
            <td width=1 />
            <td width=1 />
            <td width=1 />
            <td width=1 />
            <td width=1 />
            <td width=1 />
            <td width=1 />
            <td width=1 />
            <td width=1 />
            <td width=1 />
            <td width=1 />
            <td width=1 />
            <td width=1 />
            <td width=1 />
            <td width=1 />
            <td width=1 />
            <td width=1 />
            <td width=1 />
            <td width=1 />
            <td width=1 />
            <td width=1 />
            <td width=1 />
            <td width=1 />
            <td width=1 />
            <td width=1 />
            <td width=1 />
            <td width=1 />
            <td width=1 />
            <td width=1 />
            <td width=1 />
            <td width=1 />
            <td width=1 />
            <td width=1 />
            <td width=1 />
            <td width=1 />
          </tr>
          <tr height=11>
            <td colspan=50 bgcolor="#ffffff" style="opacity:0;filter:alpha(opacity=0)" />
          </tr>
          <tr height=1>
            <td colspan=14 bgcolor="#ffffff" style="opacity:0;filter:alpha(opacity=0)" />
            <td colspan=3 bgcolor="#000000" />
            <td colspan=33 bgcolor="#ffffff" style="opacity:0;filter:alpha(opacity=0)" />
          </tr>
          <tr height=3>
            <td colspan=13 rowspan=24 bgcolor="#ffffff" style="opacity:0;filter:alpha(opacity=0)" />
            <td colspan=5 bgcolor="#000000" />
            <td colspan=32 bgcolor="#ffffff" style="opacity:0;filter:alpha(opacity=0)" />
          </tr>
          <tr height=1>
            <td colspan=33 bgcolor="#000000" />
            <td colspan=4 bgcolor="#ffffff" style="opacity:0;filter:alpha(opacity=0)" />
          </tr>
          <tr height=50>
            <td colspan=5 bgcolor="#000000" />
            <td colspan=32 bgcolor="#ffffff" style="opacity:0;filter:alpha(opacity=0)" />
          </tr>
          <tr height=1>
            <td colspan=16 bgcolor="#000000" />
            <td colspan=21 bgcolor="#ffffff" style="opacity:0;filter:alpha(opacity=0)" />
          </tr>
          <tr height=58>
            <td colspan=5 rowspan=3 bgcolor="#000000" />
            <td colspan=32 bgcolor="#ffffff" style="opacity:0;filter:alpha(opacity=0)" />
          </tr>
          <tr height=1>
            <td bgcolor="#ffffff" style="opacity:0;filter:alpha(opacity=0)" />
            <td colspan=28 bgcolor="#000000" />
            <td colspan=3 bgcolor="#ffffff" style="opacity:0;filter:alpha(opacity=0)" />
          </tr>
          <tr height=56>
            <td colspan=32 bgcolor="#ffffff" style="opacity:0;filter:alpha(opacity=0)" />
          </tr>
          <tr height=1>
            <td colspan=24 bgcolor="#000000" />
            <td colspan=13 bgcolor="#ffffff" style="opacity:0;filter:alpha(opacity=0)" />
          </tr>
          <tr height=71>
            <td colspan=5 rowspan=3 bgcolor="#000000" />
            <td colspan=32 bgcolor="#ffffff" style="opacity:0;filter:alpha(opacity=0)" />
          </tr>
          <tr height=1>
            <td colspan=2 bgcolor="#ffffff" style="opacity:0;filter:alpha(opacity=0)" />
            <td colspan=30 bgcolor="#000000" />
          </tr>
          <tr height=62>
            <td colspan=32 bgcolor="#ffffff" style="opacity:0;filter:alpha(opacity=0)" />
          </tr>
          <tr height=1>
            <td colspan=23 bgcolor="#000000" />
            <td colspan=14 bgcolor="#ffffff" style="opacity:0;filter:alpha(opacity=0)" />
          </tr>
          <tr height=80>
            <td colspan=5 rowspan=12 bgcolor="#000000" />
            <td colspan=32 bgcolor="#ffffff" style="opacity:0;filter:alpha(opacity=0)" />
          </tr>
          <tr height=1>
            <td bgcolor="#ffffff" style="opacity:0;filter:alpha(opacity=0)" />
            <td colspan=31 bgcolor="#000000" />
          </tr>
          <tr height=59>
            <td colspan=32 bgcolor="#ffffff" style="opacity:0;filter:alpha(opacity=0)" />
          </tr>
          <tr height=1>
            <td colspan=4 bgcolor="#ffffff" style="opacity:0;filter:alpha(opacity=0)" />
            <td colspan=12 bgcolor="#000000" />
            <td colspan=16 bgcolor="#ffffff" style="opacity:0;filter:alpha(opacity=0)" />
          </tr>
          <tr height=59>
            <td colspan=32 bgcolor="#ffffff" style="opacity:0;filter:alpha(opacity=0)" />
          </tr>
          <tr height=1>
            <td colspan=2 bgcolor="#ffffff" style="opacity:0;filter:alpha(opacity=0)" />
            <td colspan=30 bgcolor="#000000" />
          </tr>
          <tr height=41>
            <td colspan=32 bgcolor="#ffffff" style="opacity:0;filter:alpha(opacity=0)" />
          </tr>
          <tr height=1>
            <td colspan=6 bgcolor="#ffffff" style="opacity:0;filter:alpha(opacity=0)" />
            <td colspan=4 bgcolor="#000000" />
            <td colspan=22 bgcolor="#ffffff" style="opacity:0;filter:alpha(opacity=0)" />
          </tr>
          <tr height=1>
            <td colspan=2 bgcolor="#ffffff" style="opacity:0;filter:alpha(opacity=0)" />
            <td colspan=4 bgcolor="#000000" />
            <td colspan=26 bgcolor="#ffffff" style="opacity:0;filter:alpha(opacity=0)" />
          </tr>
          <tr height=34>
            <td colspan=32 bgcolor="#ffffff" style="opacity:0;filter:alpha(opacity=0)" />
          </tr>
          <tr height=1>
            <td colspan=2 bgcolor="#ffffff" style="opacity:0;filter:alpha(opacity=0)" />
            <td colspan=30 bgcolor="#000000" />
          </tr>
          <tr height=5>
            <td colspan=32 bgcolor="#ffffff" style="opacity:0;filter:alpha(opacity=0)" />
          </tr>
          <tr height=1>
            <td colspan=14 bgcolor="#ffffff" style="opacity:0;filter:alpha(opacity=0)" />
            <td colspan=3 bgcolor="#000000" />
            <td colspan=33 bgcolor="#ffffff" style="opacity:0;filter:alpha(opacity=0)" />
          </tr>
          <tr height=6>
            <td colspan=50 bgcolor="#ffffff" style="opacity:0;filter:alpha(opacity=0)" />
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td>
        <table cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 height=609 width=36 style="font-size:0px;height:609px;width:36px">
          <tr height=0>
            <td width=1 />
            <td width=1 />
            <td width=1 />
            <td width=1 />
            <td width=1 />
            <td width=1 />
            <td width=1 />
            <td width=1 />
            <td width=1 />
            <td width=1 />
            <td width=1 />
            <td width=1 />
            <td width=1 />
            <td width=1 />
            <td width=1 />
            <td width=1 />
            <td width=1 />
            <td width=1 />
            <td width=1 />
            <td width=1 />
            <td width=1 />
            <td width=1 />
            <td width=1 />
            <td width=1 />
            <td width=1 />
            <td width=1 />
            <td width=1 />
            <td width=1 />
            <td width=1 />
            <td width=1 />
            <td width=1 />
            <td width=1 />
            <td width=1 />
            <td width=1 />
            <td width=1 />
            <td width=1 />
          </tr>
          <tr height=254>
            <td colspan=36 bgcolor="#ffffff" style="opacity:0;filter:alpha(opacity=0)" />
          </tr>
          <tr height=1>
            <td colspan=4 bgcolor="#000000" />
            <td colspan=32 bgcolor="#ffffff" style="opacity:0;filter:alpha(opacity=0)" />
          </tr>
          <tr height=143>
            <td colspan=36 bgcolor="#ffffff" style="opacity:0;filter:alpha(opacity=0)" />
          </tr>
          <tr height=1>
            <td colspan=14 bgcolor="#000000" />
            <td colspan=22 bgcolor="#ffffff" style="opacity:0;filter:alpha(opacity=0)" />
          </tr>
          <tr height=119>
            <td colspan=36 bgcolor="#ffffff" style="opacity:0;filter:alpha(opacity=0)" />
          </tr>
          <tr height=1>
            <td bgcolor="#000000" />
            <td colspan=35 bgcolor="#ffffff" style="opacity:0;filter:alpha(opacity=0)" />
          </tr>
          <tr height=77>
            <td colspan=36 bgcolor="#ffffff" style="opacity:0;filter:alpha(opacity=0)" />
          </tr>
          <tr height=1>
            <td colspan=15 bgcolor="#000000" />
            <td colspan=21 bgcolor="#ffffff" style="opacity:0;filter:alpha(opacity=0)" />
          </tr>
          <tr height=12>
            <td colspan=36 bgcolor="#ffffff" style="opacity:0;filter:alpha(opacity=0)" />
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>

<div id="number1">0</div>
<div id="number2">5</div>
<div id="number3">10</div>
<div id="number4">15</div>
```

Comment: Haha lol. You reproduced the same shape! even that diagonal marker :)

Comment: yes lol :D Maybe this is stupid way to do this but it works. In complex ruler this way will work even better than correct answer here

Comment: You seem to be a very generous guy. Firstly you didn't lash out at the downvoter .. and now you are thanking me for an edit!

Comment: I understand downvoter because my answer is not professional and answer of David Thomas is much better. After your edit even I changed mind about this code. Now it looks much better.

Comment: In SO snippet and even in JSfiddle, there's an option of "Tidy up" which automatically indents all the code. :)

Comment: Thanks again for helping me. I love stackoverflow more and more